# Passing data from child component to parent getting error prop.onCall not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am calling a parent function from functional child component
but I am getting error props.onCall is not a function.

Also props come as undefined when I do console.log(props)

Here is the **parent** function :

```
class Parent {
    construtor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myFun = this.myFun.bind(this);
    }
   
    myFun = val = {
    console.log(val);
    }
   
    render{
     return (
      <Child onCall={this.myFun} />
   
    )
    }
    }
```

Here is the **child** function :

```
const Child = props => {
   
    Handlefn = () => {
    props.onCall("hi");
    }
    }
```

Comment: There should be an arrow `myFun = val => {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ton of typos in your app.
Try this

Parent:

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myFun = this.myFun.bind(this);
  }

  myFun = val => {
    console.log(val);
  };

  render() {
    return <Child onCall={this.myFun} />;
  }
}
```

Child:

```
import React from "react";

const Child = props => {
  const Handlefn = () => {
    props.onCall("hi");
  };

  return <h1 onClick={Handlefn}>Hi</h1>;
};

export default Child;
```